# mondays=less moderation=spam waves=ignored questions

Tags: discussion

I have seen that on Mondays, there is a tsunami of spams(including duplicates and other flag-able questions and those requiring edits). Such questions remain in the newest list because there are very few people moderating on Mondays.As a result, good questions are also swiped away by this wave and remain unattended and unanswered.

Are we doing anything on this issue? It's just adding more to the bunch of unanswered questions on AU.

Comment: *I have seen that on Mondays(..)*, *Such questions remain in the newest list because there are very few people moderating on Mondays(...)* Do you have any metrics to support that or is this one of those "I checked the website 3 weeks on a row and made up my mind about it" facts?

Comment: @BrunoPereira: I am pretty sure thes is based on observation but are there are any weekly metrics which can help prove/disprove this claim?

Comment: @BrunoPereira I don't think I have a measuring scale to prove my theory.It's all observations.

Comment: "Duplicates and those requiring edits" are not spam, exactly..

Comment: @minerz029 I mean spams+duplicates+everything not productive.I  don't mean duplicates are spams.

Answer (score 6):

The following are entirely *possible*:

- There are fewer moderators around on a Sunday night (GMT).
- More of the moderators and users spend more time with their `$DAYJOB` on Monday morning.
- More spammers are spamming on Sunday night and Monday morning because they don't have the brains or transferable skills to hold down a job.

I'm not sure if any of those are actually true though.

We know we have a moderation window (after US goes to sleep and India wakes up) which is why there is the following in the election text this year:

> Your existing Community Moderators would also positively encourage potential moderators from the China, Singapore, Indonesia & Australia time-zones to cast their name into the ballot. Ask Ubuntu is a 24 x 7 site and we need community moderators with experience throughout the world from all walks of life.

But you have to consider that it's not just about moderators. Users can (and often do) deal with spam without having to involve a moderator, just by flagging it appropriately. *If* there is more spam present (and again, we're yet to confirm that there is such a phenomenon), perhaps this suggests there are fewer users on the site too.

And given that we're an English site, I wouldn't be surprised if more East Asian users found support elsewhere. This may ultimately just be something we have to accept and deal with.

Comment: When you consider Asia, the truth is that we are divided into two.India, Bangla, Vietnam, Philippines,afghan etc on one hand and Pak, lanka, China etc on other.We can't live together, not even in virtual world.This is why you don't see Asians on same sites generally. [mod-snip] In short, I agree with your point that east asians or asians in general find support elsewhere, but it's more political than just language problem.

Comment: @adityapatil I had to censor you a bit there. It's one thing to have opinions, it's another to broadcast them... I think I see your point though, I'd just rather think that people would be able to leave their nationalism behind them while they're on the site.

Comment: No problem.I agree I crossed the limit.But it's just the truth.It's really very painful to just watch from far and be able to do nothing for my brothels.sorry again.